# Unity equivalent to cocos2D (and Sprite Kit) Actions?

Tags: unity, cocos2d, spritekit

Does Unity have an equivalent to the Actions feature/functionality of cocos2D and Sprite Kit; if so, what is it?

**cocos2D Actions:** 
http://python.cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/actions.html
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Actions

**Sprite Kit Actions:** 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/AddingActionstoSprites/AddingActionstoSprites.html

Comment: It would help here if you clarified what functionality you're actually trying to accomplish. Depending on what use of "Actions" you want to find an analogue for, the Unity equivalent might be Coroutines, Delegates, interpolation helper functions, etc. Can you edit your question to include an example use case you'd like to translate into a Unity-style solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might like [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/index.php), which is a tween engine for Unity and a successor to HOTWeen.
It's said to be a lot faster than iTween, another tween engine for Unity. I also find it easier to use too.

I suggest you check out the [documentation page](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php). It has easing like you mentioned, among other many useful features like `Sequence`s and callbacks. It's obvious from looking at the documentation page, but it can tween many objects,  including UGUI ones.

I'm using it for my 2D game project for school to animate UGUI objects, so the features that I find particularly useful are the ones listed under "*Unity UI 4.6 shortcuts*" under "*B. The shortcuts way*" on the documentation page.
But again, you can use it to animate things like `Camera`, `Material`, `Rigidbody`, `TrailRenderer` etc etc...

About easing, DOTween's easing options include sine, quadratic, cubic, elastic and many more.

Comment: If you take away the comment about tweens and the link to tweens, are the things you're suggesting the same as Actions in cocos2D?

Comment: edit. I took it out. It was distracting from the question.

Comment: Further, the question was about Unity. Not Unity plugins and assets.

Comment: @Confused I do admit my experience with cocos2d is limited, but I think tweening(animating by translating, scaling, rotating, etc...) is precisely what cocos2d action's equivalent would be, although the plugin I suggested doesn't have something like CCTwirl and CCLiquid in cocos2d.

Comment: @Confused Oh, if you limit the scope to Unity's built-in features, I don't think there is something like cocos2d's action features.

Comment: From what I can see, the closest (in Unity) is coroutines, but they must be custom created for their purpose. There's nothing (I have seen so far) like the pre-baked functionality of Actions. Sprite Kit also offers the ability to make custom Actions, but it's a little different to how coroutines seem to work, and more "integrated" into Sprite Kit's loop.

Comment: @Confused By the way, is there a reason you only want to use built-in features in Unity ?

Comment: Many reasons. But, again, the external things you linked to, whilst featuring eases, are not the same as cocos2D Actions. Am I to assume there is nothing like Actions in Unity? My experience, so far, when programmers don't comment on something, that's a negative response.

Comment: It seems a lot of programmers have problems saying things are not possible, not available or just... NO!

Comment: @Confused, to give you actual context, *practically everything is possible*, given an *absolute* understanding of how to program it. Any case of "I can't do that" is more often a case of I don't know how to do that". It is fair to say that Unity expects *some* understanding of programming, though they do provide fairly adequate tutorials to teach you all you would need to know.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Unity have an equivalent to "Actions"?

That depends *entirely* on your interpretation of what "Actions" do, and of course, your base requirements.

---

Let's take a look at an example of an "Action", as provided by [the Cocos2d-x Wiki](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Actions):

```
// Move sprite to position 50,10 in 2 seconds.
auto moveTo = MoveTo::create(2, Vec2(50, 10));
mySprite1->runAction(moveTo);

// Move sprite 20 points to right in 2 seconds
auto moveBy = MoveBy::create(2, Vec2(20,0));
mySprite2->runAction(moveTo);
```

From what the documentation infers, `MoveTo` is an action that has been built to direct any object to a position. In this case, you appear to be creating a *delegate* function, which your object then stores reference to and runs.

---

Let's take a look at an example of how you would implement this same "Action" in Unity:

```
float speed = 10; 
Vector2 targetPosition = new Vector2(50, 10);
Vector2 newPosition = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed);
transform.position = newPosition;
```

---

You will immediately note that in Unity, you are writing the "action", yourself. As such, you should have an understanding of either Java or C#. This might seem a little more difficult than the "pre-baked Actions" of Cocos2d-x, but this is often desirable; you should still ideally only have to write the action *once*, and you have access to a lot of powerful functions provided by the `UnityEngine` namespace (alone - there are many other namespaces under the `UnityEngine` namespace). Furthermore, you can make it behave *exactly* how you want it to. For example, you would be able to edit the above script to interpret `speed` as `speed * Time.deltaTime`. This is especially useful, in this context; we need to scale our speed to the delta time of the update functions, to ensure the speed stays the same across a variation of setups and processor speed.

---

> Does Unity implement "Sprite Kit Actions"?

The same rules apply.

You can still manipulate various attributes associated with the sprite, whether that be direct values on the sprite itself to change things such as transition style and speed, or changing values on the *game object* that *holds* the sprite.

These "actions" would simply be methods you have written that manipulate these areas. You can also create variables on the animations, themselves, which can be directly manipulated with built-in functions.

---

Ultimately, it is difficult to say if Unity has "Actions", as it is hard to infer *exactly* what you *want* from the "Actions". That said, if you assume programming capability, you certainly have the ability to set the mechanic up on your own.

Than again, you may not want to. As stated previously, the example appears to show "Actions" being used as *delegates*. Unity typically expects you to call "actions" as standard functions (`MoveTo::create()` versus `Move()`). You might find that with time, you take to using the Unity method; *delegates* are considered more advanced, though you do not appear to be given the same type of control you would expect from advanced technique.

It is important to note that *regardless*, you *are* going to have to do some programming. Unity runs off Unityscript (a variation of Javascript) and C#, where Cocos2d-x runs off C++. You will find *similarities*, but you will not get absolute control by assuming C++ context. Regardless, the Unity website offers excellent tutorials, and provided you put in the effort, it will not be difficult to use code in Unity by comparison.